# Makefile PHONY usage in large file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, makefile, gnu-make

I've Makefile which use .Phony which works OK
        my question is there is cleaner way to write it instead of before each target

```
all: app1 app2 

.PHONY: app1
app1:
    echo "from app 1"

.PHONY: app2
app2:
    echo "from app 2"
```

I've lots of other targets (which looks the same), is there a cleaner way to write it instead before each target over and over again ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.PHONY` can have as many prerequisites as you wish:

```
.PHONY: all app1 app2
```

And you can put it anywhere in your Makefile, not only just before the rules of the phony targets:

```
.PHONY: all app1 app2

all: app1 app2

app1:
    echo "from app 1"

app2:
    echo "from app 2"
```

Note that if you have "*lots of other targets which looks the same*" make has some nice features that you could probably use to factorize the similarities:

```
APPS := app1 app2

.PHONY: all $(APPS)

all: $(APPS)

$(APPS): app%:
    echo "from app $*"
```

(`$*`, in the recipe, is expanded as the stem of the `app%` pattern).

Make is so smart that you could probably even let it auto-magically detect the potential targets, instead of having to explicitly list them (`APPS := app1 app2...`). But here, we need to know a bit more about your real project organization. Let's assume, for example, that each `appX` has a corresponding `appX.todo` file and that the build command is something like `buildapp appX.todo appX`. Then, the following Makefile will automate everything:

```
TODO := $(wildcard *.todo)
APPS := $(patsubst %.todo,%,$(TODO))

.PHONY: all $(APPS)

all: $(APPS)

$(APPS):
    buildapp $@.todo $@
```

(`$@` is expanded as the target of the rule).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `all` in the target

```
.PHONY: all
```

This is even shown in one of the examples in the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html):

```
all : prog1 prog2 prog3
.PHONY : all

prog1 : prog1.o utils.o
        cc -o prog1 prog1.o utils.o

prog2 : prog2.o
        cc -o prog2 prog2.o

prog3 : prog3.o sort.o utils.o
        cc -o prog3 prog3.o sort.o utils.o
```

Comment: thanks, but what if not all the target should use .PHONY ?

Comment: then just list specific targets `.PHONY: prog1 prog2`